# Xcode 4.5 , Multiple errors ocurred while copying files

Tags: xcode

I'm using xcode 4.5, and i run this steps:

1- Create a new empty application for ios

2- On this application, i create 1 group who name is 'Resources', and other sub-group who name is 'Imgs'

3- I drag images from finder into the group Imgs, and Xcode send me 'Multiple Erros Ocurred While Copyng Files', i try to click on group and go to add files, but this method send me the same messange (if i put 1 images by 1 images, don't have problem)

4-But on the real folder of my application the images who i drag, exists on the folder..

So can..can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it happens when some of the files with the same names already exists at destination location. Then you need to delete it, and copy from source to the project again.

Comment: I agree with Shmidt, I also usually avoid to copy files in Xcode dyrectories when Xcode is open.
Close it, move the files in the folder and then load the files in your solution directly from the IDE

Answer (score 1):

1.Right Click on the project 
2.Show in Finder
3.Check for the file names you are adding,If exists delete them and add them again